# Is there a patch in Microsoft Test Manager to allow for editing tests while running?

Tags: manual-testing, mstest, mtm

I am in a project which uses [Microsoft Test Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_management_tools#List_of_test_management_tools) (MTM) for running tests. Although a fairly solid piece of software, it lacks some functionality that other test management software has.

One feature I was wondering if there was a patch for is editing tests while running them. I have seen a blog post somewhere complaining that this is not possible in the straight install. I also think there may be a patch which adds this functionality.

Is there a patch which adds the "edit while running" functionality to MTM?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Test Manager (MTM) in Visual Studio 2010 does not have this ability and I am not aware of any plugins/patches that allow this to happen. Unfortunately, it does not appear that MTM in Visual Studio 2012 will have this feature either: see [this MSDN blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20150910200222/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/02/29/what-s-new-for-microsoft-test-manager-in-visual-studio-11-beta.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

This has been added in Visual Studio 2012 Update 1.
It adds an Edit button when running a test case.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you, this would be a great feature and Microsoft should consider this in a future release. I create many, many test cases for others to run and this would be a huge time saver for the whole team. Especially if when working in short sprints and constantly having to update test cases to reflect newly completed tasks and bug fixes.

**However, can you just run a second instance of MTM?**

I typically have more than one instance of MTM running: one on my host machine, and another instance in the virtual machine which I am running the test on. This allows me to make changes to the test case on my host machine instance of MTM as I go about testing on the other instance in my VM. Note: if you want two instances of MTM.exe running on a single machine (e.g. where one is in design mode and another in run mode) you'll have to launch the second MTM instance as another user as it is a [single instance application](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vstsqualitytools/single-instance-application)

Answer (score 0):

You can edit a Test Case while running it now. Here is a screenshot with the edit button.

[image]